# Separação de endereço do número com regex

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá,

Estou com um problema com expressões regulares, eu preciso separar o endereço de forma que a rua fique separado do número. Exemplo:

- “Rio Branco 23” -> {“Rio Branco”, “23”};
- “Quirino dos Santos 23 b” -> {“Quirino dos Santos”, ”23 b”}

Tentei fazer o seguinte:

```
import re
endereco = str(input('Digite o endereço com o número para separá-lo: '))
print(re.split(r'\A(.*?)\s+(\d+[a-zA-Z]{0,1}\s{0,1}[-]{1}\s{0,1}\d*[a-zA-Z]{0,1}|\d+[a-zA-Z-]{0,1}\d*[a-zA-Z]{0,1})', endereco))
```

- Porém, no exemplo de "Rio Branco 23" ele está exibindo ['', 'Rio
  Branco', '23', ''], ao invés de ['Rio Branco', '23'];
- E no exemplo de "Quirino dos Santos 23 b" ele está exibindo ['',
  'Quirino dos Santos', '23', ' b'] ao invés de ["Quirino dos Santos”,
  "23 b"].

E eu precisaria também nestes casos, que são endereços internacionais:

1. “4, Rue de la République” -> {"Rue de la République", "4"}
2. “100 Broadway Av” -> {"Broadway Av", "100"}
3. “Calle Sagasta, 26” -> {“Calle Sagasta”, “26”}
4. “Calle 44 No 1991” -> {“Calle 44”, “No 1991”}

Comment: Existe algum motivo para usar regex? Você aceitaria uma solução que não utilize regex?

Comment: Claro, aceitaria sim.

Answer (score -2):

Se não existe um motivo para a utilização de regex, procure outro modo de fazer. Até porque escrever esse regex seria bem complicado, já que a ordem das informações não é sempre a mesma, e existem diferentes marcadores que identificam números no endereço.

Não é como procurar separar informações do e-mail. "username@gmail.com" é muito simples. Só procurar o "@" e você sabe exatamente pra onde ir. Mas, pra você, o marcador pode ser uma vírgula, um "No" ou simplesmente um espaço em branco que separe palavras de um número.

Construa as condições caso a caso (pelo que vi, não são muitos casos distintos) e aí sim desenvolva lógicas específicas para eles.

Exemplo:

```
if ', ' in endereco:
    ...

if 'No' in endereco:
    ...
```

Encontrar uma solução genérica para o problema só é bom quando isso não sacrifica a legibilidade e a clareza do seu código.